# How do I stop Adobe Omniture from adding two stars (**) in front of my tracking server URL?

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

I'm working on implementing Adobe Omniture analytics for a web app that is supposed to be running on an old web browser. This is how my AppMeasurement looks like

```
enter code/************************** CONFIG SECTION **************************/
    /* You may add or alter any code config here. */
s = new AppMeasurement();
    s.charSet="UTF-8"
    /* Conversion Config */
    s.currencyCode="USD"
    /* Link Tracking Config */
    s.trackDownloadLinks=true
    s.trackExternalLinks=true
    s.trackInlineStats=true
    s.linkDownloadFileTypes="exe,zip,wav,mp3,mov,mpg,avi,wmv,pdf,doc,docx,xls,xlsx,ppt,pptx"
    s.linkInternalFilters="javascript:,ats.adobe.com"
    s.linkLeaveQueryString=true
    s.linkTrackVars=""
    s.linkTrackEvents=""


    /* WARNING: Changing any of the below variables will cause drastic
    changes to how your visitor data is collected.  Changes should only be
    made when instructed to do so by your account manager.*/
    s.visitorNamespace = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    s.trackingServer = "XXXXXXXXXXXX.2o7.net";
s.trackOffline = true;
s.offlineThrottleDelay = 2000;
```

XXXXXXXX here is my tracking server. When I check the URL inside the s object, it looks something like this:

```
"http://**XXXXXXXXXXXX.112.2o7.net/b/ss/REPORTSUITEXXXXX/1/JS-1.4.4/s74006798288…"
```

The two stars you see after http:// are added automatically by Adobe and my old browser cannot encode that to UFT-8 and the request never goes through:

```
http://%2A%2AXXXXXXXXXX.112.2o7.net/b/ss/REPORTSUITEXXXXX/1/JS-1.4.4/s
```

Is there any way to stop adobe from adding these special characters in my tracking URL ?

Comment: What is in your `doPlugins` (if you have one)? What does `s.visitorNamespace` and `s.trackingServer` show after the execution? There isn't anything in the core code that should add `**`.

Comment: Agreed. Has to be something in the configuration or tracking server. 

Also should set linkTrackVars and linkTrackEvents to "None" if you don't want your page load data to be re-sent on a link click.